# C: Does locking a pthread mutex place the thread in a FIFO queue?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Lets say **thread 1** has locked the `mutex` and does some work.

If **thread 2** calls:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

Then **thread 3** calls the same:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

Then **thread 1** unlocks the `mutex`. Does FIFO (First In First Out) apply to the threads trying to lock the `mutex`?

If so, **thread 2** would guaranteed be the next one to acquire the `mutex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does FIFO (First In First Out) apply to the threads trying to lock the mutex?

Nope, no FIFO is guaranteed.

See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3p.html:

> If there are threads
> blocked on the mutex object referenced by mutex when
> `pthread_mutex_unlock()` is called, resulting in the mutex becoming
> available, the scheduling policy shall determine which thread shall
> acquire the mutex.

On Linux pthread mutex is implemented using [futex](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` involves `FUTEX_WAKE`:

> No guarantee is provided about which waiters are awoken (e.g.,
> a waiter with a higher scheduling priority is not guaranteed
> to be awoken in preference to a waiter with a lower priority).

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the prevailing scheduling policy. If it's SCHED_FIFO, then for each priority level there really is a fifo list of waiters, and indeed futexes make allowance for this (see [futexes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html), section FUTEX_LOCK_PI). SCHED_FIFO tends to be the policy used for real time applications. The page on

Comment: Priority inversion protected mutex boosts the priority of the thread which locked the mutex, that's exactly what `FUTEX_LOCK_PI` does.